# How can I get NodaTime to update when Android updates the TimeZone?

Tags: c#, android, nodatime

I'm new to NodaTime & still finding my way around it.

If when I start my program the Android timezone is set to "America/New York"
NodaTime `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()` correctly returns "America/New_York"

However if I then update the timezone via Android settings to "America/Denver" while my program is running, then `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()` still returns "America/New_York"

How do I get the program to read the new Android System timezone & return that information?

I can't see any equivalent of `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` and running that first makes no difference to NodaTime, although both TimeZoneInfo & DateTime.Now are correctly updated

Answer (score 0):

`TzdbDateTimeZoneSource` doesn't do any caching - it fetches `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` and maps that.

So I would *expect* calling `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` to be sufficient, so long as that updates `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`.

In other words, if you run:

```cs
Log(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
Log(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault().Id);

// Pause and adjust the system default time zone.
// Then:

TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
Log(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
Log(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault().Id);
```

... I'd expect to see consistency, e.g. "America/New_York" twice and then "America/Denver" twice.

If you see "America/New_York" four times, that means `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` isn't actually updating the local time zone ID.

If you see "America/New_York" twice, then "America/Denver", then "America/New_York", then that would be a bug in Noda Time - but assuming you're using a recent version, I can't easily see how that would happen. (`DateTimeZoneCache` doesn't cache the results of `GetSystemDefault()`, nor does `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource`.)

Comment: Yes, I am seeing "America/Denver" from TimeZoneInfo and "America/New_York" from nodatime after running TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData.

Comment: @LHV: Okay, I'll look into that. Can you check whether you see the same in a regular console app from Linux or Windows? And give more details on how you're using it on Android? (Is this MAUI, something else?)

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this in WSL: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/c4dcb388d828dc2a1e8f4773e0088f45 - but that prints "Europe/London" twice, then "Europe/Paris" twice. Again, if you could give more information about how you're using it on Android, that would help. (I should be able to test it in MAUI fairly easily...) Do you see it in the emulator?